Randomize Transform overrides the original location&rotation
I'm trying to make a cube that is already shattered. The shattered pieces will rotate as they move forward fast. At the end, the pieces will locate themselves to the original cube shape like it was never shattered.
To make this, I used the cell fracture to break up the cube and added a keyframe. I moved the keyframe to the end, and used randomize transform to make the location & rotation random.
The problem is here: I made a keyframe using randomize transform at the first frame, and I tried to used the randomize transform on the 20th frame to make a more dynamic animation, while keeping the original location at the end of the frame. but as soon as I add a key frame on the 20th frame using randomize transform, the original location at the end of the frame gets affected and gets disrupted, allowing the original location to be altered. I must keep the original location & rotation at the last frame but I think the randomize transform overrides the existing keyframe. What should I do at this point?
